# How to set a Textarea to 100% height in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to set a `textarea` to be 100% height. I'm using [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/) but couldn't find an option there.

```
<div class="container">
<textarea class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
</div>
```

How to do it?

Comment: Why not just use `height: 100%`?

Comment: @Zhihao Because it doesnt work that way, using boostrap and all the predefined  default settings.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
html, body, .container {
  height: 100%;
}
textarea.form-control {
  height: 100%;
}
```

See [demo on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6WEDU/)

Answer (score 8):

I believe this is a bootstrap issue. I ran into a similar problem where the textarea was not allowing for more than 1 row. I found (through trial and error) that placing the textarea in a div and then ignoring the form-group-(x) call within the first div, I was able to control the rows and the cols within the textarea.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Description</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Changing your code to use the form-group functionality will correct the issue:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
</div>
```

That should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
textarea { 
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried? It doesnt work. This is a **bootstrap** issue.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't work for me for bootstrap 3- davidkonrad
You can try to modify the number of rows

```
<textarea class="form-control" cols="60" rows="16"></textarea>
```

or give a height fixed for the parent container

```
.form-group{
   height:250px;
 }
textarea{
   height:100%;
}
```

Comment: `<textarea class="form-control" cols="60" rows="16"></textarea>`  This is working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS:

```
textarea {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Relative to the top layer.

Comment: Have you tried? It doesnt work. This is a **bootstrap** issue.

Comment: Yes, but without `block`. My fault. See the jsfiddle, I told you, you need to consider the main container before, like `davidkonrad`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I am using Bootstrap 3 as well. My textarea is inside a container.

```
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solves my problem.. I set the height to auto !important.

```
<label for="item_description" style="padding-top: 10px;">Item Description</label>
<textarea class="form-control" name="item_description" rows="3" style="height:auto !important;"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.textarea {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Text Area</title>
</head>

<body>

  <textarea class="textarea"></textarea> 
  <h3>subscribe to my youtube channel<a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsZ4Ue8c94YLJDbGRafCI5Q">The Gem Dev</a></h3>
</body>

</html>
```

This worked for me, i placed it in a container

```
.textarea {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.textarea .text {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: edit and add a working code snippet so users can test the code